# Send a HTML site by email?

Tags: html, ios, email

It is possible to send an entire site (that has only 1 image, a logo) via mail?, the workflow would be:

- user opens the mail
- user sees the attachment "html" file
- user clicks the attachment, the browser opens.

I have no idea if this is possible.

Another thing, this has to work on mobile, iOS more precisely.

Until now we were sending interactive pdfs to the users, but now we want to include iOS users as well, so this strategy could work, if it works of course.

And unfortunately, no, I can't send a link to a website, it has to work this way, for reasons that are beyond my decision.

Comment: "it has to work this way, for reasons that are beyond my decision." Without knowing what these reasons are, it is difficult to advise you. My first thought is that most any modern email client can already handle HTML email, so just send the "site" (page) inline.

Comment: The client wants for it to work as a pdf file, it means, the user receives the file, and then opens it. No apps involved. Another thing is, the html site that is sent by mail is quite complex, lots of css, js, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have three options:

1. Send a link to your website.
2. Send the mail with an attachment of the HTML of your website. (since it is simple, you said just 1 image and logo it can fit in one HTML file).
3. Send an HTML formatted email, where you display the image and the logo.

If you want it to work on mobile, just use media querys for it to change styles depending on widht and height of the device.

Comment: No, its not simple, it is a quite complex site, I only said that is has only one image, the rest is filled with js, css, etc.

Comment: It can still apply option number 2. Your JS will still run.

Comment: When you say "can fit", does it mean that if the site is big, it wont?.

Comment: I mean if it is only one HTML file, not more. Obviously you can attach a compressed website if your website has more than one HTML files.